# How do I set a background image in iOS with transparency using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm able to set a patterned background using the following code

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "imagefilename")!)
```

It works fine but the image is a png with transparency and I think because of this the transparent areas are coming our as black, is there a way of enabling the transparency so the background colour shows through?

Comment: are you sure, there is another view behind the one you are modifying?

Comment: That's a very good point, so it would it be a case of creating a new view and setting background image that way?

Comment: yes. then you can even set the color of the transparent parts of the image

Comment: I feel slightly silly now, makes perfect sense. Could you put that in an answer so I can mark it? Also, what would be the best way of creating a new view programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see a black background, because there is no view behind the view you are modifying.

If you can't change your image (to make it non-transparent), you could add a subview to your view containing this image:

```
//create a new UIView
let otherView = UIView(frame: view.frame)
otherView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "imagefilename")!)

//now add your new view as subview to the existing one
view.addSubview(otherView)
```

The transparent parts should now be white by default. You can change this by modifying `view.backgroundColor`.

**Note:** If you add other UI-elements, they might be hidden under `otherView` because they are added as subviews of `view`. To prevent this, you can add them as subview of `otherView` or reorder the layers. (`view.bringSubviewToFront(anotherUIElement)`)

---

I wrote all the code on the fly, so there might be some syntax errors. But the general idea behind this code should work.